# Hooking bash commands?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I'm tired of doing long `cd` commands to other directories, so I want to make a little tool for jumping to the most recent folders.

I've searched and haven't found any sort of API that would let me trigger a process when a `cd` command is run. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Working off the `bash_history` seems inefficient, and isn't always enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a classic bash script that makes easier directory navigation: http://linuxgazette.net/109/marinov.html

Comment: Seems like this is just what I was looking for and makes my question moot. For those coming from Google, the link does answer the question, the author of the script gives a good overview of the implementation (and tackles the problem by adding his script the `bashrc` file and using `alias` to override the cd command)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`pushd` and `popd`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC87).

Comment: One advantage of pushd is that you can reference directories on the stack using ~<n>, e.g. "cp ~2/file ."

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a fairly recent version of bash you can just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type a few letters to get the history. So, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cd` you'll get your last `cd` command. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again and you're get second last `cd` command and so on.

And yes, `cd -` takes you to your last working directory.
You can also find your last working directory in shell variable `$OLDPWD`